# What are options or tools to autocreate ERD for Progress Openedge ABL?

Tags: automation, relational-database, diagram, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm currently immersed with the process of creating ERD's for a largely undocumented database built with Progress Openedge ABL. 
[Progress recommended solutions:](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P123587)
I'm curious if anyone has experience with these recommended solutions?

Alternatively, are there resources not cited in this link that would improve efficacy?

Comment: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Answer (score 1):

We're using Zamolxis http://acorn.ro/products/zamolxis/

License fees are very moderate for that kind of tools and it's integrated into Progress Developer Studio.